# SFML: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

Tags: c++, sfml

```
  while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Process events
        sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
         if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))()&&accelerationx > 15;
         {
   accelerationx = accelerationx + 5;
         }
         if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A))()&&accelerationx > 0;
         {
   accelerationx = accelerationx -5;
         }
         if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))()&&accelerationx > 15;
         {
   accelerationy = accelerationy + 5;
         }
         if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))()&&accelerationx > 0;
         {
   accelerationy = accelerationy - 5;
         }
   speedx = accelerationx + speedx;
   speedy = accelerationy + speedy;
   sprite.move(sf::Vector2f(0.f+speedx, 0.f+speedy));

        }
   // Clear screen
   window.clear();
   // Draw the sprite
   window.draw(sprite);
   // Update the window
   window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Returns:

> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token

New to C++ and SFML so apologies if this is a stupid question. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dui erat, blandit eget facilisis ac, euismod non metus.

Comment: Delete the `{` before `//Clear Screen`

Comment: The error should tell you the line number

Comment: I think you are missing several ) in your if () {} statements. I mean you have `if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))()&&accelerationx > 0;` why the `;` and why not `)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Expression (condition) after the `if` must be in parentheses `()` and NOT terminated by semicolon `;`.

If you have only 1 command in the `if` block, you need not put it between braces `{}`:

```
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) && accelerationx > 15)
       accelerationx = accelerationx + 5;
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) && accelerationx > 0)
       accelerationx = accelerationx -5;
```

Moreover, it is nicer to use assignment operators (`+=`, `-=`) for increasing / decreasing values:

```
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) && accelerationx > 15)
       accelerationx += 5;
   if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) && accelerationx > 0)
       accelerationx -= 5;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but now getting:error: expression cannot be used as a function On the line of every if statement?

Comment: `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D))()` probably should be `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)` the () part makes the compiler think  you want to call a function. Also after this change I believe you then have an extra `(` at the beginning.

Comment: @drescherjm, thank you, you're right, I fixed it in my answer.

Comment: @baguettio, I fixed the sample code in my answer by the advice of  drescherjm. Please fix it in other similar parts of your code, too.